# Gazebo GPS Noise Model

Tags: gazebo, gps, gazebo-plugin, noise

What is the Gazebo GPS Sensor Noise Model based on? It looks like a Random Walk through the code, but would be great if I could get some confirmation about it.

Also, is HDOP and VDOP (DOP - dilution of precision) modeled in the sensor?